# CodeName One size of 1mb

Tags: size, cross-platform, codenameone

If I have the free account,with a JAR size limit of 1mb,I want to understand 
approximately what can or can't I do with this limit;Is this limit too small to make an app?I want that my app have access to camera,web browsers and that cointains images,few videos,a lots of documents??

Comment: Have you read at Codename one website, in the pricing section?

**Free users have a JAR size limit of 1mb. Notice that this is a very high limit as it applies only to your bytecode and not to Codename Ones libraries. You can create pretty remarkable apps within this limit, in fact all of our demos fit within it. Notice that the resulting app size isn't under quota neither for free or paid users.**

Answer (score 1):

The 1mb size applies to the jar sent to the server, this is around 6kb for a barebones application. All of our demos and many 3rd party apps in the stores fall under this limit which is generally a good approach.

It doesn't limit the size of the final application or 3rd party libraries used which means you can still use a large library like google maps without hitting this limit. If you use a very heavy theme or many images (within the app JAR not downloaded dynamically) you will hit this limit.

There is a bit of an overview here on how to shrink the JAR overhead https://www.codenameone.com/blog/shrinking-sizes-optimizing.html

Notice that I'm currently working on a fully functioning clone of the Uber application which is currently under 600kb.